# how to write a file uploaded to the form to disk?

Tags: node.js, express

The application collects data from the form, including files, and sends it in the "formData" format.

```
 let formData=new FormData();
    formData.append("user",data.user);
    for(let i=0;i<data.images.length;i++){
        formData.append(data.images[i].name,data.images[i],data.images[i].name);
    }
    await fetch("/api/upload",{method: "POST",body:formData });
```

When receiving data on the server, you need to save it. I tried to write using fs.writeFile but got an error " The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of File". My handler:

```
router.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
let keys=Object.keys(req.files);
fs.writeFile(keys[0],req.files[keys[0]],(err)=>{
    console.log(err)
})});
```

How do I save the file correctly?

Comment: you should rethink this; if you scale out your servers (more than one), you will not be able to fetch the files bc some are stored on server 1 and some are stored on server 2. rather, you should look towards an NFS (maybe S3) to store these contents so its shared.

Comment: @LostJon in my case the "nodejs" server has access to the server "frontend" files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turned out that you can take a link to it from the file in the temp folder, read and write with fs:

```
router.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
console.log(req.files)
let keys=Object.keys(req.files);
fs.readFile(req.files[keys[0]].path,(err,e)=>{
    if(err) console.log(err);
    fs.writeFile(keys[0],e,(err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
})});
```